# Сверить 2 элемента Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется кнопка с 2 состояниями: активное и неактивное (кликнули - еще не кликнули).

Найдены по CssSelector:

```
IWebElement abcd = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("is-active"));

IWebElement zxy = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("is-not-active"));
```

При неактивном(is-not-active) необходимо кликнуть по ней. Делаю это с помощью:

```
Actions press = new Actions(driver);
        press.MoveToElement(zxy).Build().Perform();
        press.Click(zxy).Build().Perform();
```

При активном состоянии(is-active) необходимо просто закрыть окно.

Как правильно сверить эти 2 состояния? if-else что-то не работают с элементами Selenium :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует искать кнопки по более постоянным критериям, которые не изменяются в зависимости от состояния. Дальше следует делать проверку класса, что он содержит is-active.

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button"));
if(button.GetAttribute("class").Contains("is-not-active"))
{
    button.Click(); //Этот клик более стабилен и выдаст исключение если кликнуть не удастся
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо за ваш ответ. Вопрос решил с помощью try-catch :)